# I need to pass date from json to my controller

Tags: java, rest, date, thymeleaf

Hi i am a newbie with dates.

**This is my controller. And i want to pass my string date instead of Instant.now ().**

```
@PutMapping("/edit")
  public void edit (@RequestBody Client client) {
     clientService.update (client.getId (), Instant.now ());
  }


 public interface ClientService {
     Subscription update(String clientId, Instant myTime);
 }


${#temporals.format(client.myTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

My entity

```
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("myTime")
  @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
  private OffsetDateTime myTime;

public OffsetDateTime getMyTime() {
    return myTime;
  }

  public void setMyTime(OffsetDateTime myTime) {
    this.myTime = myTime;
  }
```

When i try to pass client.getMyTime() to edit() i have this:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type
> `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2021-05-05": Failed to
> deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.DateTimeException)
> Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved
> to 2021-005-05 of type java.time.format.Parsed; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException

How to resolve it? How do I need to pass date from front-end to my controller?

Comment: Are you using Thymeleaf HTML templates or REST JSON API? Are you using `@Controller` or `@RestController` ?

Comment: Yes i use Thymeleaf

Comment: And i use RestController

Comment: So you are using Thymeleaf to display the HTML page (via a `@Controller`) and then use JavaScript to issue an AJAX request towards your REST API (using `@RestController`), correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `java.util.Date` object.

```
private Date myTime;
```

Format is not required.

Comment: Any specific reason for using OffsetDateTime?

Comment: There are many uses of OffsetDateTime in my project. it will be very problematic to switch to something else.